# Solving the heat equation for varying thermal diffusivity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The classical heat diffusion equation 1D is of the form:

$\begin{align}
\rho C_p \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial (k \frac{\partial T}{\partial x})}{\partial x}
\end{align}
$

with $\rho$, the density, $C_p$, the specific heat capacity, $T$ the temperature, and $k$ the thermal conductivity.

I want to solve numerically a problem where I only have an expression for $\alpha$, the thermal diffusivity, that depends on T, so when it is not constant in space and in time.

$\alpha$ is formally simply equal to:

$\begin{align}
 \alpha = \frac{k}{\rho C_p}
\end{align}
$

I have seen papers where they solve:

$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial (\alpha \frac{\partial T}{\partial x})}{\partial x}
\end{align}
$

My question is simple: what is the justification to put $\alpha$ in the derivative, when clearly $\rho$ and $C_p$ are not in it in the first expression? Is that fine to do so if $\rho$ and $C_p$ are also changing through space?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hi! It is clearly not fine to do that in full generality. In the paper you have seen they are very likely making as an assumption that the density and heat capacity are constant. It is an extremely common thing to do in mathematics papers and books to make simplifications in your physical model without explicitly justifying every single one of them

Comment: The density and heat capacity only change slightly in most scenarios, so can be treated as constant.

Comment: Thx you both. I was starting to doubt my mathematical skills.. @LorenzoPompili The paper in question is a Nature paper where they consider density constant but NOT the heat capacity ([here](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature07818)). Equation 5 clearly show the thermal diffusivity is in the derivative even though they show that the heat capacity change through space. So I am a bit puzzled.. For me, they should have recalculated the thermal conductivity from Cp and the thermal diffusivity and use that in the derivative. But I guess they know better than me why they did it like this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, in their model they assume $\kappa$ and $C_p$ depend on the temperature $T$ itself. So yes, in principle they will indirectly depend on space and time. Starting from your formula, it is clear that if $C_p$ depends on $T$, you will not end up with the equation of the paper. You would get an error term of the following form if my calculation is correct:
$$ -\frac{k}{\rho}\frac{C_p’(T)}{C_p^2(T)} (\partial_xT)^2 =-\alpha\frac{C_p’(T)}{C_p(T)} (\partial_xT)^2. $$
I suspect they are making a simplification coming from the physics of the problem. One could try looking at the above error term and understand if it is negligible in the regime of the paper. It looks not so complicated, but I don’t see it immediately.
You could try asking on PhysicsSE if you are interested in these considerations.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Would you mind elaborating on how you came up with the error term? Sorry if it is basic, as you may have understood, I'm coming from geosciences so my maths skills are not the best. I will ask on PhysicsSE for the physical aspect. MathSE may not be the best place indeed.